# Exportar campo Text para Bytea no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, text, byte

Eu poderia fazer uma aplicação para exportar o conteúdo de um campo Text para Bytea sem problemas, mas como são milhares de registros creio que se eu fizer via SQL será mais rápido.

Se isso for possível claro.

Tenho uma tabela com um campo Texto tipo Text, o conteúdo desse campo é um texto complexo, preciso transformar esse texto e RTF (RichEdit) e depois grava-lo no campo Auxiliar tipo Bytea, que recebe arquivos binários.

Tem como dar um UPDATE de um campo Text para um Bytea?

Exemplo:

```
update tabela1 set campobytea = campotexto
where (codigo = 1234)
```

Tentei com CAST, mas ele não consegue transformar o conteudo texto em binario

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/475FEAE6.7090902%40archonet.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a funcao *convert_to* que retorna bytea:

```
update tabela1 
set campobytea = convert_to(campotexto, 'UTF8')
where (codigo = 1234)
```